# Enabling Web Application Support in IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.0

Tags: java, web-applications, intellij-idea

I am trying to enable Web Application Support for a new Java project.  I am following the steps mentioned in the following support page.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/enabling-web-application-support.html

On step 3; the guide asks me to select the Web Application check box under Additional Libraries and Frameworks.  However I do not see such an option.  The only entry under Additional Libraries and Frameworks is 'Groovy'.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are using using Ultimate edition which has these plugins built in? Have you installed the plugins it needs if you are using community edition?

Comment: I am using community edition.  I have not installed any plugins.  Can you please guide me on how to do this?

Comment: I am using community edition.  I have not installed any plugins. After seeing your comment, I searched and followed this guide:

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/installing-updating-and-uninstalling-repository-plugins.html

I clicked on  Browse Plugins, but don't know which plugins I need.  Can you please help me in identifying which ones I need for enabling Web Application Support?

Comment: I don't do web development, but I also have the ultimate version so I have no idea. (Not sure it's even possible to install everything, some are available)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition does not support the development of Web applications. You need to use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate for that. Refer below link to check whether you have features you are looking for or not.
This link has full description of what each edition can do.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html?IC